# offset scrollbar to appear beside child div

Tags: html, css

I have a "pop-up" table which is a fixed element. The table is sometimes to high to fit on some screens so I have set `overflow` to `auto`. However the scrollbar appears detached from the pop-up table as the parent div is the width of the screen and the table is less. Is there a way to get the scroll bar to attach directly right of the pop-up table without the gap, while keeping the table centered? here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ssjkgb22/32) to show you what I mean. Thank you.

**html**

```
<div id = "blanket">
  <div>
    <table align = "center" id = "popUpTable">
      <tr>
        <td>fixed pop uptable</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>one</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    
        <td>three</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    
        <td>four</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>    
</div>

<div>background stuff<br>background stuff<br>background stuff<br></div>
```

**css**

```
#blanket{
      position:fixed;
      top:0%;
      bottom:0%;
      left:0%;
      right:0%;
      background-color:rgba(255,555,255,0.5); 
      overflow-y:auto;
}

#popUpTable{
         border:1px solid gray;
         margin-top:2%;
         background-color:#fff;

}

#popUpTable td{
            height:150px;
            text-align:center;
            border:1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the "background stuff", another scroll bar?

Comment: yeah, that should be default with the body property being overlfow:auto

Comment: is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ssjkgb22/33/

Comment: it's exactly that. Brilliant. Thank you. I'll upvote comment. If you want to make it answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `position:fixed; left:0; right:0;`, that makes it 100% width.

You should remove `right:0`, and set some `padding` on the left for displaying the "background stuff" content.

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ssjkgb22/33/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported in IE, but adding this will to you stylesheet will do what you want in Firefox Chrome and Safari, with proper centering.

```
width:-moz-fit-content;
width:-webkit-fit-content;
margin:auto;
```

See it here:
http://jsbin.com/yetoto/1/watch?css,output

When `width` is not `auto`, setting both `margin-left` and `margin-right` to auto will center things. But you need a value for `width` that will just fit your content, and `fit-content` does just that, in the browsers that support it.